# how I use multiple SUM with multiple LEFT JOINS

Tags: mysql

```
SELECT 
`members`.`id` AS `aid` , 
SUM(CASE WHEN `agents_deductions`.`loan_status` = 0 THEN `amount` ELSE 0 END) AS `deduction_amount` , 
SUM(`portion`) AS `total_portion` 
FROM `members` 
LEFT JOIN `agents_data` ON `members`.`id` = `agents_data`.`agent_id` 
LEFT JOIN `agents_deductions` ON `members`.`id` = `agents_deductions`.`agent_id` 
LEFT JOIN `agents_commission` ON `members`.`id` = `agents_commission`.`agent_id` 
GROUP BY `members`.`id` ORDER BY `members`.`id`
```

The `total_portion` results is not correct

how I use multiple SUM with multiple LEFT JOINS

**UPDATE**

I have 3 tables `members`, `agents_data`,  `agents_deductions`, `agents_commission`

I want to view all members and calculate `agents_deductions.amount` and `agents_commission.portion`

[image: members]

[image: agents_deductions]

[image: agents_commission]

members
agents_deductions
agents_commission
I want to calculate `agents_deductions.amount` it should be 12000
also calculate `agents_commission.portion` it should be 166666.7
 for the `members`.`id` = 1

**UPDATE**

I tried

```
SELECT
(
SELECT *, 
`frist_step`.`id` AS `aid`, 
SUM(CASE WHEN `agents_deductions`.`loan_status` = 0 THEN `agents_deductions`.`amount` ELSE 0 END) AS `deduction_amount` 
FROM `members` AS `frist_step`
LEFT JOIN `agents_deductions` ON `frist_step`.`id` = `agents_deductions`.`agent_id` 
WHERE `membership` != 'l_client' AND `membership` != 'l_super_client' AND `branches` LIKE '%l_contact%' AND 1
GROUP BY `frist_step`.`id` ORDER BY `frist_step`.`id` 
), 
(
SELECT *, 
`step_two`.`id` AS `aid2` ,
SUM(`agents_commission`.`portion`) AS `total_portion` 
FROM `members` AS `step_two`
LEFT JOIN `agents_commission` ON `step_two`.`id` = `agents_commission`.`agent_id`
WHERE `membership` != 'l_client' AND `membership` != 'l_super_client' AND `branches` LIKE '%l_contact%' AND 1
GROUP BY `step_two`.`id` ORDER BY `step_two`.`id`
),
(
SELECT * FROM `frist_step` 
LEFT JOIN `step_two` ON `frist_step`.`aid` = `step_two`.`aid2` 
GROUP BY `frist_step`.`aid` ORDER BY `frist_step`.`id` 
)
```

the results Error Code: 1146. Table 'frist_step' doesn't exist

Comment: "not correct" is quite vague - please describe it more completely. I don't see why you are using `LEFT JOIN`s., a `[INNER] JOIN` would seems more appropriate and save you trying to `SUM` over null values. What table(s) are `amount` and `portion` from?

Comment: Remove the `GROUP BY` from the and change `SUM( {fields} ..)` to just the fields and see if that query shows the same rows you have above.

Comment: 1) Specify table alias for EACH field in the query text. 2) Calculate sums you need in subqueries before joining. Summation after joining will multiply the sum by the amount of the corresponding records in the other tables.

Comment: @Akina sorry can you write the statement as i cannot figure out it

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try

```
SELECT members.id AS aid, 
       ad.deduction_amount, 
       ac.total_portion 
FROM members 
LEFT JOIN ( SELECT agents_deductions.agent_id, SUM(agents_deductions.amount) deduction_amount
            FROM agents_deductions
            WHERE agents_deductions.loan_status = 0
            GROUP BY agents_deductions.agent_id
          ) ad ON members.id = ad.agent_id
LEFT JOIN ( SELECT agents_commission.agent_id, SUM(agents_commission.portion) total_portion
            FROM agents_commission
            WHERE agents_commission.loan_status = 0
            GROUP BY agents_commission.agent_id
          ) ac ON members.id = ac.agent_id
ORDER BY members.id
```

PS. I do not understand why the `agents_data` table is included in the query data source. None of its field is used in a query (except join condition) and it cannot affect to the query result because of left join (except unwanted multiplying).